# Leaflet js : text is not showing on map

Tags: leaflet

here is my jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/5abu963o/. i made provision so a yellow color text should be lying on map but not working.

here is the js part only i like to highlight.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var map = L.map('map').setView([49.2, 16.5], 10);
  new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

  L.marker(new L.LatLng(49.2, 16.5), {icon:createLabelIcon("textLabelclass","a place")}).addTo(map);
  L.marker(new L.LatLng(49.25, 16.4), {icon:createLabelIcon("textLabelclass","another place")}).addTo(map);
  L.marker(new L.LatLng(49.15, 16.37), {icon:createLabelIcon("textLabelclass","place 3")}).addTo(map);
  L.marker(new L.LatLng(49.21, 16.38), {icon:createLabelIcon("textLabelclass","place 4")}).addTo(map);

})

var createLabelIcon = function(labelClass,labelText){
  return L.divIcon({
    className: labelClass,
    html: labelText
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to call the `createLabelIcon` function before it is defined.

I updated the code on the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5abu963o/1/) you provided by putting the `createLabelIcon` function on top and the code is working now.